# jQuery callback function to check number of child elements on element click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of "div" whose children count I want to check when a user fadeOut images under that div block, if the all childrens have be closed out i want to call the function: kind of like:

> edited: the current code always alerts YES whenever the div is faded,
>   how do i destroy the DOM entirely without having to use :visible
>   filter.  getting rid of the entire card class after fading out
>              considering the HTML:

```
<div class='scrolling-wrapper'>
  <div class='card'>
    <div class='panel panel-primary'>
      <div class='panel-body'>
        <div class='img-wrap'>
          <span class='close-x'> &times; </span>
          <img width='100%' id='3' class='' src='resizer/resizer.php?file=profiles/images/default_cover.jpg&width=700&height=400&action=resize&watermark=bridgoo&watermark_pos=tl&color=255,255,255&quality=100' />
        </div>
        <div class='title h5'>
          <span class='user-popover'>
                        <a href='/groupstomason/'><b>tomason</b></a>
                        </span>
          <br/>
          <small class='small-text'>for max tomason
                        </small>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='panel-heading'>
        <button class='btn btn-primary'> <span class='fa fa-plus-circle fa-fw'> </span>Join </button>    
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='card-group-holder' style='width:250px; background-color:inherit;'>    
    </div>
   <div class="card"> another card</div>
    <div class="card"> another card</div>
   <div class="card"> another card</div>
  </div>
```

and the jquery below:

```
$('.img-wrap .close-x').on('click', function() {
  var card = $(this).closest('.card');
  card.fadeOut('slow', function() {
    var cardWrapper = $(this).closest('.card').closest('scrolling-wrapper');
    var cardcount = cardWrapper.children('.card');
    if (cardcount.length < 1) alert('yes');
  });
});
```

> when the  `<span class = 'close-x'> &times; </span>` is clicked the
>   entire `<div class='card'>` is fadedOut, then on fadeout, if  no more
>   cards exist or the last cards have been faded, then `alert('yes');`

Comment: So your set of divs are `card`?

Comment: there are multiple card added dynamically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that multiple `.card` elements are nested in the same parent, you can check if all the siblings have faded out.

In your original markup, you have an unclosed `</div>`, which causes the `.card` elements not to be siblings of each other, I believe this is a typo on your part, since it is the most parsimonious explanation.

Since `.fadeOut()` hides the element, you can simply check if the filtered set of `:visible` returns a length of 1 or more:

```
$('.img-wrap .close-x').on('click', function() {
  var card = $(this).closest('.card');
  card.fadeOut('slow', function() {
    var cardWrapper = $(this).closest('.scrolling-wrapper');
    var cardcount = cardWrapper.children('.card');
    if (cardcount.filter(':visible').length < 1) {
        console.log('All cards have faded out');
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    var card = $(this).closest('.card');
    card.fadeOut('slow', function() {
    
      // Get wrapping ancestor
      var cardWrapper = $(this).closest('.scrolling-wrapper');
      var cardcount = cardWrapper.children('.card');
      
      // Filter out those that are not visible, and check for remaining visible cards
      if (cardcount.filter(':visible').length < 1) {
        console.log('All cards have faded out');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/* Just styles for a dummy call-to-action element in .card */
span.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="card">Card 1. <span class="close">Click to hide me.</span></div>
  <div class="card">Card 2. <span class="close">Click to hide me.</span></div>
  <div class="card">Card 3. <span class="close">Click to hide me.</span></div>
  <div class="card">Card 4. <span class="close">Click to hide me.</span></div>
  <div class="card">Card 5. <span class="close">Click to hide me.</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add the class selector full stop token: `$(this).closest('.scrolling-wrapper');`

Comment: @Santi `.fadeOut()` only fades the element out and does not remove it, so checking the number of `.cards` will not work as it will always be non-zero.

Comment: @Santi Your code makes no sense at all: the `.card` elements are not siblings to each other, of course it will not work.

Comment: First off, I never posted any code so I'm not sure what you mean by "my code makes no sense". That being said, this was my mistake: I didn't realize that you changed OP's `alert()` to a `console.log()` and was under the impression yours wasn't firing. Apologies.

Answer (score 2):

In your callback you may simply test if at least a card is visible:

```
if ($(this).closest('.card').siblings('.card:visible').length < 1) alert('yes');
```

```js
$('.img-wrap .close-x').on('click', function () {
  var card = $(this).closest('.card');
  card.fadeOut('slow', function () {
      if ($(this).closest('.card').siblings('.card:visible').length < 1) console.log('yes');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class='scrolling-wrapper'>
    <div class='card'>
        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
            <div class='panel-body'>
                <div class='img-wrap'>
                    <span class='close-x'> &times; </span>
                    <img width='100%' id='3' class=''
                         src='resizer/resizer.php?file=profiles/images/default_cover.jpg&width=700&height=400&action=resize&watermark=bridgoo&watermark_pos=tl&color=255,255,255&quality=100'/>
                </div>
                <div class='title h5'>
                    <span class='user-popover'>
                        <a href='/groupstomason/'><b>tomason</b></a>
                        </span>
                    <br/>
                    <small class='small-text'>for max tomason
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='panel-heading'>
                <button class='btn btn-primary'><span class='fa fa-plus-circle fa-fw'> </span>Join</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='card-group-holder' style='width:250px; background-color:inherit;'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='card'>
        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
            <div class='panel-body'>
                <div class='img-wrap'>
                    <span class='close-x'> &times; </span>
                    <img width='100%' id='3' class=''
                         src='resizer/resizer.php?file=profiles/images/default_cover.jpg&width=700&height=400&action=resize&watermark=bridgoo&watermark_pos=tl&color=255,255,255&quality=100'/>
                </div>
                <div class='title h5'>
                    <span class='user-popover'>
                        <a href='/groupstomason/'><b>tomason</b></a>
                        </span>
                    <br/>
                    <small class='small-text'>for max tomason
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='panel-heading'>
                <button class='btn btn-primary'><span class='fa fa-plus-circle fa-fw'> </span>Join</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='card-group-holder' style='width:250px; background-color:inherit;'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```